# Does windows update show updates installed if the updates were installed manually?

Tags: wsus, patch-management

I am investigating a new system in our environment.

When I got to Windows Update it displays that there never has been any updates.[image: Windows Update Example]

This machine is connected to a WSUS Server.  I know that the "Updates were installed:" field will list the date that updates were last installed.

Will this display field list anything if updates were displayed manually?  Using an executable for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will this display field list anything if updates were displayed manually?

Yes.  You can also `View Update History` using the link in the left, which will list it, among other methods, like checking installed updates in the control panel, or running `systeminfo` from a command line.